# In Spider-Man 2 on PS5, does it matter what character you play for main story missions?

Tags: marvels-spider-man-2

I’m early into *Marvel’s Spider-Man 2* on PS5. There seem to be some side missions that you have to complete specifically as either Miles or Peter as they’re geared towards their story (e.g. paying a visit to Uncle Aaron is a Miles mission, which makes sense). It seems like the main story missions can be started as either one, so does it matter which one I use? Specifically, are there different cut-scenes or other content that I might miss, so I would need to remember who I played a mission as so I can do the opposite on a second play-through?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each story mission has to be completed with a specific character.

The story missions will still show up as objectives regardless of which character you are currently playing as but when you start the mission it will swap you to the correct one.

Comment: Thanks. One of my few experiences so far shows the mission in the FNSM app with either Miles or Peter as an option, hence my question.